# Fatal Exception When I want to read From a website

Tags: java, android

I have FATAL EXCEPTION when try to get data from a web site;
my code is here,

this is my code Java class:

```
public class TestInternetClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            URL url=new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream stream=connection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(stream);
            StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
            int temp=reader.read();
            while (temp!=-1){
                builder.append((char)temp);
             temp=reader.read();
            }
            reader.close();
            stream.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            return builder.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Log.i("InternetData",s);
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

and in the main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TestInternetClass testInternetClass=new TestInternetClass();
       testInternetClass.execute("https://www.gsm.ir/");

    }
}
```

my manifest:

```
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

this is my Error:

```
11-07 23:46:07.318 9703-9703/com.fr6ad.testweathwe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.fr6ad.testweathwe, PID: 9703
 java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
     at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:211)
     at com.fr6ad.testweathwe.TestInternetClass.onPostExecute(TestInternetClass.java:53)
     at com.fr6ad.testweathwe.TestInternetClass.onPostExecute(TestInternetClass.java:19)
     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: manifest: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: It seems that the 's' in Log.i is null. But I am astonished that Log.i does not handle that itself. You should insert a null check before the call to Log.i

Comment: You're passing a `null` to `Log.i("InternetData",s);`

Comment: BTW: As you do not use HTTP POST, you should take off the line ` connection.setDoOutput(true);`

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman I watch a move for learning android. in move its work! and in the MainActivity Execute

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `null` from your `doInBackground()` function and your `onPostExecute(String s)`'s `Log.i` call doesn't expect a null argument. Like others have said, adding a null check will correct the immediate issue, but it masks a larger underlying issue. That issue being, you've thrown either a MalformedURLException or IOException.

The immediate fix is to simply add a null check

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    if(s == null) Log.e("InternetData", "Null was returned by the background task!");
    else Log.i("InternetData", s);
    super.onPostExecute(s);
}
```

However, I highly recommend you find out what else is going on in your code and what the real error is with regards to the MalformedURLException or IOException you are throwing.

Comment: thas is right, but i want to get data from a website. on MainActivity i run this code:  execute("www.anything.com"), but its null yet,

Comment: @FarGh Right, so you are likely throwing one of your two caught exceptions. What is the stacktrace getting printed right before the error?

Comment: W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.google.com
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
 W/System.err:     at com.fr6ad.testweathwe.TestInternetClass.doInBackground(TestInternetClass.java:30)
 W/System.err:     at com.fr6ad.testweathwe.TestInternetClass.doInBackground(TestInternetClass.java:19)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)

Comment: W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

Comment: @FarGh you need to add the protocol. Try passing "`http://www.google.com/`" instead.